# Where are the Opens stored for Mobile Push messages in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush

Hi fellow SFMC developers,

I am trying to build a journey that sends two push messages: first one to the entire audience and a Push notification reminder to those recipients who have not opened the first push message.

As I understand, the Engagement split activity is not useful in this case, so I need to find a way to access the openers of the Push messages to make this happen using a Decision split activity.

Could anyone please tell me how can I access the Opens for Mobile Push? Is there a data view or a data extension or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no data view to query directly, but you can set up an Automation to run the [Push Message Detail Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_push_message_detailed_report.htm&type=5) that places a file on the FTP that you can then import to a data extension to use as the basis for decision splits. There's also the [MobilePush Detail Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5) that you can ask Support to provision that extracts much the same data as you see in the report.

You will need to add the data extension holding the detail report records to your Contact Model in order to facilitate decision split activities.